# Creating Hundreds of Matrices

Tags: r, matrix, automation, wordle-game

Project Background: I have about ~10,000 rows of numbers that are formatted as shown in the screenshot. These numbers correspond to Wordle answers and I need to convert each block of numbers into its own matrix. I began doing it by hand using:

```
22201
02000
00010
22200
22222
w1 <- rbind(c(2,2,2,0,1),c(0,2,0,0,0),c(0,0,0,1,0),c(2,2,2,0,0),c(2,2,2,2,2))
```

But with over a thousand wordle answers needing to be converted to Matrix form this would take untold hours. Does anyone know how I could automate a process that would convert each block of 0's,1's, and 2's into a matrix?

[Screenshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W24pn.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Don't spam tags please.

Comment: You've essentially got a fixed width file with no spaces between values - `read.fwf("wordle.txt", widths=rep(1,5))` might do it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `strsplit` on each string and then do a single `do.call(rbind, ..)` on the results.

```r
wordle <- readLines("~/Downloads/wordle.txt")
wordle
# [1] "22201" "02000" "00010" "22200" "22222" "21202" "11220" "22222"
wordle <- readLines("~/Downloads/wordle.txt")
wordle
#  [1] "22201" "02000" "00010" "22200" "22222" "21202" "11220" "22222" "11111" "22222"
fun <- function(z) do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(z, ""), as.numeric))
split(wordle, c(TRUE, cumsum(wordle[-length(wordle)] == "22222")))
# $`0`
# [1] "02000" "00010" "22200" "22222"
# $`1`
# [1] "22201" "21202" "11220" "22222"
# $`2`
# [1] "11111" "22222"
lapply(split(wordle, c(TRUE, cumsum(wordle[-length(wordle)] == "22222"))), fun)
# $`0`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    2    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    2    2    2    0    0
# [4,]    2    2    2    2    2
# $`1`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    2    2    2    0    1
# [2,]    2    1    2    0    2
# [3,]    1    1    2    2    0
# [4,]    2    2    2    2    2
# $`2`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    2    2    2    2    2
```

Walk-through:

- `strsplit(wordle, "")` splits strings into individual letters (in a list):

  ```r
  strsplit(wordle, "")[1:2]
  # [[1]]
  # [1] "2" "2" "2" "0" "1"
  # [[2]]
  # [1] "0" "2" "0" "0" "0"
  ```
- `lapply(.., as.numeric)` is because ultimately we want them to be numbers, not strings; the use of `lapply` preserves the `list`-structure we *need* for `do.call` to work.
- `do.call(rbind, list(a, b, c))` is analogous to `rbind(a, b, c)`, but without having to type each of the elements of the list. This means the single `do.call(rbind, ..)` will work whether the text file has 10 or 10000 entries. We write this into a `fun`ction for each of applying it to many sub-matrices.
- `cumsum(wordle[-length(wordle)] == "22222")` helps us group the data based on the *previous* element being `"22222"`. We feed this to `split` so that we have a list of vectors where the last string in a vector is all twos.
- We then `lapply` across that list of split vectors and apply our `fun` (`do.call(rbind, ...)`) on each vector (each of which ends with `"22222"`).

As for determining if any particular attempt has been seen previously, we can use `duplicated`:

```r
duplicated(wordle)
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

where the two `TRUE`s happen to be the second and third `"22222"`, because they were seen previously in the original vector. If you want to see repeated non-`2`s attempts, then you can do something like

```r
duplicated(wordle) & wordle != "22222"
```

Comment: Thank you.. I was actually looking to create many matrices and not one giant five column, ~1000 row matrix, but I think this might work.. However, I need to be able to check if a new matrix (wordle entry) already exists in the giant matrix that you just made. The point of this project is to see if a new wordle submission (the 1's,2's, and 0's - not the word itself) has already been submitted by another user at some point in the past... If this makes sense, do you have any ideas how I could make this work? Apologies for all the questions, I'm still quite new.. Thanks!

Comment: (1) "Many matrices", sure, but your input data is just a set of five. Am I to assume that when five-2s are found, you want a new matrix? If so, it generally helps to have that listed explicitly in your sample data. (2) "check if a matrix exists" ... I do not understand. Do you mean `duplicated(wordle)` on my original vector?

Comment: See my edit, LiamBrothers, it addresses (I think) both of your comments.

Comment: Apologies... No duping intended... I wasn't able to use the previous answers in the way that I needed so I thought I'd repost and try again.. Your answer was much more helpful, for what it's worth.  I'll be sure not to double post in the future.

Comment: It appears I've been censored, LiamBrothers. My last comment was intended to be candid, not mean: if it went too far then my apologies.

Comment: Not at all... I certainly didn't downvote or report you.. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: The lapply function worked for the majority of matrices (i.e. I now primarily have five column matrices that end in 22222), but some matrices contain two or three "22222's" and, for some reason, have three additional columns with a smattering of 0's, 1's, 2's, and NA's... If this would require you to download my txt/rmd files to do more digging, do not worry about it... But if you suspect you might know what the problem is, further clarification would be greatly appreciated.. Thank you again for the help, and sorry for the "censoring" headache.. Best, Liam.

Comment: It's really not easy to know without seeing a clear example of what failed, tbh. If you can figure out which block of guesses in your file is mis-identified and create a sample with that block and the blocks before/after it, it'd be easier tor esolve.